Logs are not being saved to the logfile after generating a build on Jenkins
In my Flutter application, I create a file on the device where the app is installed to store logs. In build development it works, saves logs in the file, but when I generate a build on Jenkins, the file is created, but the logs are no more saved in the file.
I am using:

logger package;
getApplicationDocumentsDirectory() from path_provider;
All applications permissions on android and iOS.

I am using the logger like this:
final List<Directory> dirs = await Future.wait([
    getApplicationDocumentsDirectory(),
  ]);

  final Directory documentsDir = dirs[0];

  final File logFile = await LoggerService(documentsDir: documentsDir).init();
  final Logger myLogger = Logger(
  level: Level.all,
  printer: PrettyPrinter(
    dateTimeFormat: DateTimeFormat.dateAndTime,
    colors: true,
  ),
  output: MultiOutput(
    [
      ConsoleOutput(),
      FileOutput(
        file: logFile,
      ),
    ],
  ),
);

LoggerService
class LoggerService {
  final Directory documentsDir;
  final String loggerPath;

  LoggerService({
    required this.documentsDir,
    this.loggerPath = '/path/to/my/logs',
  });

  Future<File> init() async {
    final Directory dir = Directory('${documentsDir.path}$loggerPath');

    if (!dir.existsSync()) {
      await dir.create(recursive: true);
    }

    final String formattedDate = DateFormat('yyyyMMdd').format(DateTime.now());
    final String logFilePath = '${dir.path}/app_$formattedDate.txt';
    final File logFile = await File(logFilePath).create(recursive: true);

    return logFile;
  }
}

In debugging mode, the logs are being saved to the file correctly.
Why is this happening and how to solve?

Does it work if you put filter: ProductionFilter(), in your Logger ?

Hi, I tried yesterday, and now the logs are being saved on the file. Thanks for answering!
